# CodeIgniter and Smarty

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I have associative array:

Model

```
public function selectArticle(){
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM articles");
    return $sql->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function index(){  
    $data['articles'] = $this->article->selectArticle();  
    $this->parser->parse('index.tpl', $data);   

}
```

Template

```
{foreach from = $articles item = $article}  
<tr>  
    <td width="30%">{$article.title}</td>  
    <td width="30%">  
                <a href="{$article.link}" target="_blank">http://example.net</a>  
    </td>    
    <td width="20%">{$article.size}</td>  
    <td width="20%">{$article.count}</td>  
</tr>  
{/foreach}
```

How get fild in template?
As now: article.fild - not work

Comment: I cannot remember, but sould it not be `{$article->title}` etc. in smarty?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what doesn't work? Is the page completely blank? Does the page load but not info is printed? Can you dump the articles array to see what's inside it from the view? All this will help us get to the answer quicker.

Comment: Rekire, he returns the sql data with ->result_array(). Codeigniters native response is to return an object. That's why you see $article->$title. But since he returned it as an array he's using the correct syntax.

Comment: {$article-> title} not working/

Comment: what is fild?  is it in your array somewhere?

Comment: Try to do a `print_r($data['articles'])` in your `index()` function. What does it output? I can't see anything wrong with your template.

Comment: {$article->title} not workink

Comment: @JohnB I think he means `article.field` - as in he cannot access any variables in `article`.

Comment: index.tpl and the array is not empty

Comment: @systemiv No, your syntax in the foreach loop is correct [according to the Smarty 2 manual on `foreach`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl). You are using Smarty 2, right? Not 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove **$article**, have to use **article**

> *{foreach from=$articles item=**$article**}*

**Try this code:**

```
{foreach from=$articles item=article}
<tr>
    <td width="30%">{$article.title}</td>
    <td width="30%"><a href="{$article.link}" target="_blank">http://example.net</a></td>
    <td width="20%">{$article.size}</td> 
    <td width="20%">{$article.count}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: I think Olaf has it. But doesn't he need to do the same thing for $articles in the FROM statement? -- Mark his answer correct if it works.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification, Olaf. :)